# Django app for different clients

Tags: django, deployment, client

I want both mobile phones and regular PCs to be able to use my app by navigating to the same URL, but I want them to get different versions of the code. How do I tell Django to give different versions of the code to different clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect the HTTP_USER_AGENT from your view. Read more about it on [django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/).